# expected identifier in function declaration swift

Tags: swift, swift2

When i upgrade swift 1.2 to swift 2.0 following error occurs

> expected identifier in function declaration swift

here is code

```
internal func try(block: () -> Int32) {
    perform { if block() != SQLITE_OK { assertionFailure("\(self.lastError!)") } }
}
```

can you help how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try` is a keyword in Swift 2.0 for the `do ... try ... catch ...` statement, so you should change the name of your function, for instance:

```
internal func myTry(block: () -> Int32) {
    perform { if block() != SQLITE_OK { assertionFailure("\(self.lastError!)") } }
}
```